# Access temporary variable removal from query design

Tags: ms-access, vba

I know you can remove a temporary variable through VBA command: `tempvars.remove "variablename"` however this doesn't actually remove the variable from the query itself. Because I have built a query, and in design view that temporary variable is used in the "criteria" section for the query, is there a way through VBA to either remove that temporary variable from the query itself or to return all possible values?

Is it possible to set a temporary variable for instance to "show all values" essentially removing the specified criteria?

I am using all bound forms which is why I don't set the query on the fly.

Comment: Can you post the SQL query with the temp var?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a query which references a `TempVar` in its `WHERE` clause, similar to this ...

```sql
WHERE some_field=[tempvars]![variablename]
```

Later you remove that `TempVar` ...

```vb
tempvars.remove "variablename"
```

However, removing the `TempVar` does not alter the query's SQL.  You would need to revise the query manually or write VBA code to revise it.

But that might not be necessary.  After you remove a `TempVar`, any attempt to reference its value does not trigger an error.  Instead, Access just gives you Null.

You can use that fact to your advantage in the query's design:

```sql
WHERE
    some_field=[tempvars]![variablename]
    OR
    [tempvars]![variablename] Is Null
```

When `[tempvars]![variablename]` exists, the query will return only rows whose *some_field* values match the `TempVar` value.

And when `[tempvars]![variablename]` is gone, Access will give you Null, which means the second condition, `[tempvars]![variablename] Is Null`, will be True for all rows.

Comment: You da man HansUP simple and intelligent solution to my problem